# JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated when using xsl on remote test server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, websphere-liberty

We are having an issue with an adapter procedure that uses xsl… To isolate I created a new adapter and ran with the example procedures (getStories, getStoriesFiltered) via procedure invocation via a direct HTTP request and via a native mobile application (iOS).

“Just in case” both procedures were tested both without the securityTest attribute and with.

In the case of getStories (which has no xsl filtering) the result was returned on both the http request and the native app. This is both in the local dev WL server and when deployed to the remote WL test server.

In the case of getStoriesFiltered (which has an xsl filter) on the local dev WL server it runs fine. With the adapter deployed to the remote WL test server we get an error… details are:

Error  from Invoking from a browser:

> /*-secure- {"errors":["Verify Error: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013
>   class loading constraint violated;
>   class=org/apache/xalan/xsltc/dom/SAXImpl,
>   method=getAxisIterator(I)Lorg/apache/xml/dtm/DTMAxisIterator;,
>   pc=0"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/

Error from invoking from a native mobile client (iOS):

> 2014-05-16 16:36:46.681 iOSNativeApp[1109:60b]  Procedure Invocation
>   Failure: Invocation failure. /*-secure-
>   {"responseID":"1","errors":["Verify Error: java.lang.VerifyError:
>   JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated;
>   class=org/apache/xalan/xsltc/dom/SAXImpl,
>   method=getAxisIterator(I)Lorg/apache/xml/dtm/DTMAxisIterator;,
>   pc=0"],"isSuccessful":false,"WL-Authentication-Success":{"wl_remoteDisableRealm":{"userId":"null","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"null"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"userId":"u9eb8v4tpofoartngepouli22q","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"u9eb8v4tpofoartngepouli22q"},"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"userId":"10C0FDF9-8537-47E7-99B3-99E41ABC7956","attributes":{"mobileClientData":"com.worklight.core.auth.ext.MobileClientData@2b13dac8"},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"10C0FDF9-8537-47E7-99B3-99E41ABC7956"},"wl_anonymousUserRealm":{"userId":"484ed960-5aaf-48b0-a05d-166e38613d47","attributes":{},"isUserAuthenticated":1,"displayName":"484ed960-5aaf-48b0-a05d-166e38613d47"}},"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/

Running Worklight on Liberty.

Answer (score 0):

Please always mention your Worklight version when asking a question...

In any case, this specific error is due to a regression in recently released versions of Worklight:

- 5.0.6.2-IF201403101802
- 6.0.0.2
- 6.1.0.1

An iFix for 6.1.0.1 should be released shortly, with iFixes for 5.0.6.2 and 6.0.0.2 to arrive soon.

To access an iFix, login to [IBM Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/) and download the latest iFix available for your version of Worklight (released on or after May 15th)

Comment: Hi Idan, thanks for your very fast response. We will try the fix on Monday. And yes, stupid of me, I should have mentioned the Worklight version.